# Maintain a Queue of Strings for each ID in Database

Tags: php, mysql, queue, scalability

I have a MySQL table which has a column for ID. It is an autoincremented integer and is the primary key of the table.

I need to maintain a queue of strings(tags) for each row in my table(for each ID you can say, since that is the primary key).

For example :- Queue for ID = 1 could be 'hello','idontknow','bye'

Queue for ID = 2 could be 'idontknow','whoareyou','bye'

The maximum length of the queue could go upto 10.

A periodic script running on my server would delete a member(string) from the queue each time, for all IDs. And would update the remaining into the table. For example: for ID = 1, 'hello','idontknow','bye', 'hello' will get removed and the updated column value would be 'idontknow','bye'.

All of this is happening at scale. At a click, a new member(string) could be added to the queues for all the rows in the table.

What is the best way to manage this? Should i have a column(comma separated string of members in queue) in my table which adds a member to the queue(column) each time? And upon the retrieval, deletes the  member and updates the updated value in the column.

or should i have separate table in the DB, which will have multiple rows for each ID. The rows would contain the members of queue individually. In this case, to 10k inserts could happen concurrently. And on retrieval, 10k deletes could happen concurrently.

What do you suggest? Which is the more scalable way?

**DB Structure for second method:**

**Customers Table**

ID, Name

Now queue needs to be maintained for each customer in another table.

**Queue Table**

ID(Primary key of this table), CustomerID(Foreign key from Customer Table), 
String(String of member in queue)

So i will need to fetch from the queue table, by CustomerID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your table to this:

```
id | CusomterID | string
---+------------+----------
 1 |          1 | hello
 2 |          1 | idontknow
 3 |          1 | bye
 4 |          2 | something
```

Then your whole table is the queue. It makes reading the next job in the queue really simple, and it makes updating the queue really simple.

Comment: So Queue_id denotes the ID (foreign key) in main table?

Comment: Yea, what is the `queue_id` a foreign key of? Maybe `queue_id` is not the right term. The grouping seems important to you, if it's not, you can leave it off (and have just `id` and `string`).

Comment: Umm basically you meant that for each ID, i store the queue members in different rows in another table. And delete them on retrieval?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: I get your point. Is this scalable? I'll need to have an index in the DB for queue_id since retrieval is very time sensitive. Retrievals need to be really fast.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show the other tables? Where do these queued strings go when you process them?

Comment: There is only one table right now with primary key as ID. I need to store a queue of strings for each row in my table. The queued strings when retrieved, are passed on to another service. They are no longer needed in the database.

Comment: Ok, then `id` and `string` is enough.

Comment: So i would need to have an index on the column ID right? to quickly get the members in the queue for that specific ID?

Comment: I don't understand that part. Why are you fetching items based on their ID? It's a queue right? So first-in-first-out. I expect the fetch to be: `SELECT id, string FROM queue LIMIT 1`. Then when you have the `id` you can do `DELETE FROM queue WHERE id = #`. Then you need the index.

Comment: Actually fetches need to be made by their ID. The whole table is not a queue actually. Only rows with same ID is treated as a queue. An external service will call my API regularly with an ID. I need to give them latest member in queue and delete it.

Comment: Updated Question. Please check.

Comment: Yea ok, that's fine. You can do: `id | CustomerID | string`. Have an index and autonumbering on `id` and an index on `CustomerID`.

Comment: Thanks. Would this be scalable? Inserting or deleting 10k rows per minute in this table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89588/discussion-between-kanishk-dudeja-and-halcyon).

Comment: Try it. I think it'll work. If you need more performance consider changing the storage engine to MEMORY which will keep the entire table in memory (so no disk writes ever).

Comment: But if the server is restarted, all my data is lost. So i need to have disk backup as well.

Comment: You can always write the data to disk before bringing the server offline. This isn't rocket science. If it's crucial that no data is ever lost, then you don't want to use MEMORY.

Comment: Yes. I'll try to maintain the same table in Memcached. And read from there. If not found in Memcached, then il read from DB. Thank you for your help. :)